# Generic OnClickListener for ImageViews android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Hi I have the following structure in my layout

```
    <LinearLayout..

    <ImageView
    id=1
..
    />
    <ImageView
    id=2
..
    />
    <ImageView
    id=3
..
    />
    <ImageView
    id=4
..
    />

    /LinearLayout>
```

The images are dynamically loaded from a `List<ImageTextObject>` which always has a size 4.

```
   class ImageTextObject{
    Drawable d;
    String str;    
    int a
    ...

    }
```

I know I can get the Id inside onClickListener from `view.getId()` , but is there anyway I can get the ImageTextObject of the imageView Clicked inside a single OnClickListener.

ie

```
View.OnClickListener genericListener= new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // find which ImageTextObject is clicked.
    }
  };
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood your problem than you can use Map when u assign it a drawable.like:-
`Map<String,ImageTextObject> map = new Map<String,ImageTextObject>();`

and put it

`map.put(""+view_id,ImageTextObject_object);`

and get it later using

```
View.OnClickListener genericListener= new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // find which ImageTextObject is clicked.
      Your_object = map.get(""+v.getId());

    }
  };
```

Comment: Then I will get that string only right? The real object I need has more member variables

Comment: but you specified your class with only two variables

Comment: Sorry ..I meant it as a dummy object to show what I want to achieve.I will edit it to show it more clear.

Comment: Ok.. `List<ImageTextObject>` is your list from which you are loading drawables. right?

Comment: craete a `Map<String,ImageTextObject> map = new Map<String,ImageTextObject>()` and put it as `map.put(view_id,ImageTextObject_object);`
and get later by key (view id)...